# Is there a way to abort a Jenkins job based on new gerrit events?

Tags: jenkins, gerrit

I have a job triggering after a gerrit submit has happened. This job releases a new version, i.e. runs a maven target to increase the version and then build a new war artifact. The problem I'm facing is that if I submit say 3 changes in a row, all three will trigger the jenkins job. Let's say that when the first commit is submitted, the project version is `v1.2.3`.

```
o---------x----o----o
1:v1.2.3  J    2    3
```

When the first commit is merged, Jenkins starts releasing a new version out of that commit on that branch. Then 2 more commits come in. Jenkins finishes releasing the version and tags the release but the commit is lost because it diverges from commit `1`.

```
o----------o----------o
1:v1.2.3   2:v1.2.4   3
 \
  \___ v1.2.4 + tag:v1.2.4
```

The tag exists in the system but for the other two commits the new version is virtually non-existent. Then they try to update and tag based on v.1.2.3, tag 1.2.4 exists and the process fails.

Is there a way to change the process above to be more robust or abort the initial build after new commits are submitted on the same branch?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use "git tag --force" to create the tag.

```
-f, --force
           Replace an existing tag with the given name (instead of failing)
```

Or use GitPublisher feature of the [Git Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Git+Plugin) on Jenkins.